# Convert from row values to columns with id column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this data:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), title = c("Google-Amazon","Amazon-Google-Yahoo","Yahoo-IMDF"), status = c("Open-Open", "Wait-Close-Open", "Close-Open"))
```

and I would like to take an output like this:

```
  id Google Amazon Yahoo IMDF
   1   Open   Open    NA   NA
   2  Close   Wait  Open   NA
   3     NA     NA Close Open
```

What I tried until now is this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(titlenew = strsplit(as.character(title), "-")) %>% 
    unnest(titlenew) %>%
    mutate(statusnew = strsplit(as.character(status), "-")) %>% 
    unnest(statusnew)
```

What steps can I do after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to split the rows of 'title', 'status' with `separate_rows` and then do a `spread` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    separate_rows(title, status) %>%
    spread(title, status)
#  id Amazon Google IMDF Yahoo
#1  1   Open   Open <NA>  <NA>
#2  2   Wait  Close <NA>  Open
#3  3   <NA>   <NA> Open Close
```